# How to filter out more then one hit in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I'm trying to create a filter that will find multiple entities by Id in my elastic instance.

For instance I would like to find each Entity that contains an Id of either 34, 38, and 41.

My query is as follows:

```
    {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "id":[34, 38, 41]
            }
         }
       }
     }    
   }
```

This only returns the 41 Entity instead of 34, 38, and 41.  How can I properly return the results that match any of the Id's that are listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `term` when you mean `terms`. This was a bug in ES 1.x.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "id": [34, 38, 41]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: In ES 2.x+, this *should* be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "id": [34, 38, 41]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only change was `filtered` became `bool`.